# Concat multiple form input values using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, concatenation

I am very new to HTML/javascript. I'm attempting to create a form with four fields: the first field (`texta`) is `readonly`, the second field (`selectiona`) is a dropdown list, the third field (`textb`) is `readonly`, and fourth field (sentence) is a concatenation of the three other fields. I can't figure out why my javascript isn't working:

```js
<script>
$('#texta, #selectiona, #textb, #selectionb').bind('keypress blur', function() { 
    $('#sentence').val($('#texta').val() + ' ' +
    $('#selectiona').val() + ' ' +
    $('#textb').val() + ' ' +
    $('#selectionb').val() );
});
<script>
```

```html
<p>Text A:<input id=texta readonly value="My favorite car is a: "></p>
<p>Selection A: <select id=selectiona>
 <option>Select...</option>
 <option>Toyota</option>
 <option>Honda</option>
 </select></p>
<p>Text B: <input id=textb readonly value="because they are "></p>
<p>Selection B: <select id=selectionb>
 <option>Select...</option>
 <option>reliable.</option>
 <option>fun to drive.</option>
 </select></p>
<p>Sentence: <input id=sentence readonly></p>
```

Comment: Select options doesn't have value attributes, so select value is empty

Comment: your code is working, it change when you focus the sentence field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should work fine if you add the quotes around the HTML tags attributes.

**NOTE 1:** Your JS code is a valid code, but it will be better to replace `bind` by `on` since the `bind` method was dedicated since jQuery version 3, check :

```
$('#texta, #selectiona, #textb, #selectionb').on('keypress blur', function() {
```

**NOTE 2:** Your code will be more efficient if you give all the elements you want to attach the event to a common class, then attach the event to this class :

```
$('.common_class').on('change input', function() {
```

Also you could use `input` event for `input`'s & `textarea`'s and `change` for `select`'s.

```js
$('#texta, #selectiona, #textb, #selectionb').bind('input change', function() {
  $('#sentence').val($('#texta').val() + ' ' +
    $('#selectiona').val() + ' ' +
    $('#textb').val() + ' ' +
    $('#selectionb').val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>Text A:<input id="texta" readonly value="My favorite car is a: "></p>
<p>Selection A:
  <select id="selectiona">
    <option>Select...</option>
    <option>Toyota</option>
    <option>Honda</option>
  </select>
</p>
<p>Text B: <input id="textb" readonly value="because they are "></p>
<p>Selection B:
  <select id="selectionb">
    <option>Select...</option>
    <option>reliable.</option>
    <option>fun to drive.</option>
  </select>
</p>
<p>Sentence: <input id="sentence" style="width:70%" readonly></p>
```

Comment: replace `id="text"` into `id="texta"` otherwise, your snippet is wrong

Comment: Good point, me too, but he may enable them in another event... who knows :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use "on change" :

```js
$('#selectiona, #selectionb').on('change', function() { 
    $('#sentence').val($('#texta').val() + ' ' +
    $('#selectiona').val() + ' ' +
    $('#textb').val() + ' ' +
    $('#selectionb').val() );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Text A:<input id=texta readonly value="My favorite car is a: "></p>
<p>Selection A: <select id=selectiona>
 <option>Select...</option>
 <option>Toyota</option>
 <option>Honda</option>
 </select></p>
<p>Text B: <input id=textb readonly value="because they are "></p>
<p>Selection B: <select id=selectionb>
 <option>Select...</option>
 <option>reliable.</option>
 <option>fun to drive.</option>
 </select></p>
<p>Sentence: <input id=sentence readonly></p>
```